# Take n last rows of a dataframe with no NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's take this dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Col1 = [1,2,np.nan,4,5,6], Col2=[4,np.nan,5,np.nan,1,5]))

   Col1  Col2
0   1.0   4.0
1   2.0   NaN
2   NaN   5.0
3   4.0   NaN
4   5.0   1.0
5   6.0   5.0
```

I would like to extract the n last rows of df with no NaN.
Could you please help me to get this expected result ?

```
   Col1  Col2
0     5     1
1     6     5
```

EDIT : Let's say I don't know where is the last NaN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with [`DataFrame.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) and converting to integers:

```
N = 2
df1 = df.dropna().tail(N).astype(int)
#alternative
#df1 = df.dropna().iloc[-N:].astype(int)
print (df1)
   Col1  Col2
4     5     1
5     6     5
```

EDIT: For last group with no missing values compare misisng values with [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), then swap order with cumulative sum, so last group has `0` values in mask:

```
m = df.isna().any(axis=1).iloc[::-1].cumsum().eq(0).sort_index()
df1 = df[m].astype(int)
print (df1)
   Col1  Col2
4     5     1
5     6     5
```

If no row match it return correct empty DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Col1 = [1,2,np.nan,4], Col2=[np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan]))
print (df)
   Col1  Col2
0   1.0   NaN
1   2.0   NaN
2   NaN   5.0
3   4.0   NaN

m = df.isna().any(axis=1).iloc[::-1].cumsum().eq(0).sort_index()
df1 = df[m].astype(int)
print (df1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Col1, Col2]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I don't know where is the last NaN, how could I find the value of your N ?

Answer (score 2):

another way is to use `isna` with `drop_duplicates` and `cumsum` to get the max index and then just use index filtering

```
last_na = df.isna().cumsum(axis=0).drop_duplicates(keep='first').index.max() + 1


new_df = df.iloc[last_na:]

print(new_df)
Col1    Col2
4   5.0     1.0
5   6.0     5.0
```